# ASP.NET Identity 2.0: How to rehash password

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, hash, asp.net-identity-2

I am migrating users from a legacy user store to ASP.NET Identity 2.0 in my ASP.NET 5.0 web application. I have a means of verifying legacy hashes, but I want to upgrade them at login-time to ASP.NET Identity 2.0 hashes.

I've created a custom `IPasswordHasher` that is able to detect and verify legacy hashes, and return `PasswordVerificationResult.SuccessRehashNeeded` at the appropriate time. (If it detects that the hash is not legacy, it simply falls through to the built-in ASP.NET Identity hash verification.)

However, returning `PasswordVerificationResult.SuccessRehashNeeded` doesn't seem to cause ASP.NET Identity to actually do anything. Is there a configuration option somewhere that would cause the system to re-hash the passwords when IPasswordHasher returns this result?

If the answer is no to the above, then is it recommended that I simply re-hash and update the user manually? Where would I do this? I don't see any place at the controller level where I can see the PasswordVerificationResult.

I'm new to ASP.NET Identity so I'm sure I'm missing something simple. Thank you in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 8):

It seems rehashing mechanism is not implemented in the built-in user manager. But hopefully you could easily implemented. consider this:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    protected override async Task<bool> VerifyPasswordAsync(
          IUserPasswordStore<ApplicationUser, string> store, 
          ApplicationUser user, string password)
    {
        var hash = await store.GetPasswordHashAsync(user);
        var verifyRes = PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(hash, password);

        if (verifyRes == PasswordVerificationResult.SuccessRehashNeeded)
           await store.SetPasswordHashAsync(user, PasswordHasher.HashPassword(password));

        return verifyRes != PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add `await store.UpdateAsync(user);` after setting the new password hash to actually write the updated information back to the database. It should be done within the same `if`, so remember to enclose the updated code in brackets. (This is, by the way, a good reason to always have brackets around block statements, even when there is initially only one statement in the block.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have implemented `IPasswordHasher` correctly, when returning a `PasswordVerificationResult.SuccessRehashNeeded` result, ASP.NET Core Identity will call the `HashPassword` method automatically for you, successfully authenticating the user and updating the hash in the database.

The class would look something like this:

```
public class PasswordHasherWithOldHashingSupport : IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>
{
    private readonly IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser> _identityPasswordHasher;

    public PasswordHasherWithOldHashingSupport()
    {
        _identityPasswordHasher = new PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>();
    }

    public string HashPassword(ApplicationUser user, string password)
    {
        return _identityPasswordHasher.HashPassword(user, password);
    }

    public PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedPassword(ApplicationUser user, string hashedPassword, string providedPassword)
    {
        var passwordVerificationResult = _identityPasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(user, hashedPassword, providedPassword);

        if (passwordVerificationResult == PasswordVerificationResult.Failed)
        {
            /* Do your custom verification logic and if successful, return PasswordVerificationResult.SuccessRehashNeeded */
            passwordVerificationResult = PasswordVerificationResult.SuccessRehashNeeded;
        }

        return passwordVerificationResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: OP implemented  `IPasswordHasher` correctly. As your answer implies, the problem is that ASP.Net Identity (unlike ASP.NET Core Identity) doesn't actually support `SuccessRehashNeeded`.